# Cannot get rid of duplicate rows

Tags: sql

When I run this query I get multiple family member with the same address and I only want one row per family/address.

```
SELECT distinct last_name, first_name, address_1, city, state_code, zip_code
from guest
WHERE address_1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP by last_name, first_name, address_1, city, state_code, zip_code
```

Comment: `select distinct` applies to ALL fields in your field list, it's not `select distinct(last_name)`, it's more like `select distinct(last_name, first_name, etc...)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want one row per family/address, just drop the first name from the query, like this:

```
SELECT last_name, address_1, city, state_code, zip_code
from guest
WHERE address_1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP by last_name, address_1, city, state_code, zip_code;
```

I also dropped the `DISTINCT`, since you have a `GROUP BY`, it's not necessary.